# R data.table: use optimised mean() function in composite call?

Tags: r, data.table

I want to compute in R `data.table` deviations from group means. To do this efficiently, I would want to use the optimised `mean` function in data.table, but haven't found a way to use it within a *composite* call (i.e. `x - mean(x)`)?

What I mean is that I can use `x[, lapply(.SD, function(x) x - mean(x)), by=id]`, but I suspect that this approach does not use the *optimised* version of mean in data.table. Indeed, comparing the speed of:

1. `x[, lapply(.SD, mean), by=id]`
2. `x[, lapply(.SD, function(x) mean(x)), by=id]`

It turns out that in some cases 1) is 10 times faster than 2)! So how could I use a call like in 1), but this time for a composite function like `x -mean(x)`? I did not succeed using anonymous call `{...}` within  `lapply`.

Thanks!

#### Simulation showing how faster `mean` versus `function(x) mean(x)` is:

```
library(data.table)

T = 50 
N = 20000
set.seed(123)
data_sim <- data.table(A = rnorm(N * T),
                       B1 = sample(c(0,1), N * T, replace = TRUE),
                       B2 = rnorm(N * T),
                       individual = rep(1:N, each = T))

library(microbenchmark)

mean2 <- function(x) mean(x)

microbenchmark(sol1 = data_sim[, lapply(.SD, mean), by=individual],
               sol2 = data_sim[, lapply(.SD, mean2), by=individual],
               sol3 = data_sim[, lapply(.SD, function(x) mean(x)), by=individual],
               dev_mean = data_sim[, lapply(.SD, function(x) x- mean(x)), by=individual],
```

Results:

```
|expr     |       min|      mean|       max| neval|
|:--------|---------:|---------:|---------:|-----:|
|sol1     |  17.67686|  18.68033|  21.04078|     5|
|sol2     | 369.69595| 378.91943| 400.77024|     5|
|sol3     | 149.57088| 154.76857| 159.93155|     5|
|dev_mean | 218.44641| 286.00977| 404.06092|     5|
```

Comment: see `?GForce` and also switch on `verbose=TRUE`

Comment: Chinsoon's comment explains why you see the speed difference, but I can't figure out how to apply it to this problem. I think if https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1414 is done, it could be like `DT[, mu := mean(x), by=g][, v := x - mu]` (except with lapply and Map to iterate over columns), but the mean is not yet optimized with `:=`.

Comment: Thanks @chinsoon12 for the `verbose=TRUE` argument, which explains the speed difference! But indeed, not sure how to apply in my context? And I think according to @Frank, there's little hope to use the optimized mean for my problem? Solution then seem is to compute table of group means (use gforce), and bind it back to original table!? This explains why solution in this [similar post](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/203513/group-wise-deviations-from-means-centering-with-dplyr-vs-data-table?noredirect=1#comment392946_203513) worked so well!?

Comment: @Frank, do you want to write your comment as an answer? I think you got the right answer, that it's just not possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, by-group `mean` optimization (see `?GForce`) is not available with `:=`, though [it has been proposed](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1414).

Once it is available, something like `DT[, mu := mean(x), by=g][, v := x - mu]` should work (with `lapply` and `Map` inserted when applying to multiple columns).

In the meantime, there may be some speedup from

```
mDT = DT[, .(mu = mean(x)), by=g]
DT[mDT, on=.(g), mu := i.mu]
DT[, v := x - mu]
```

... though I'm not sure, since this involves two group-by operations.